# Setting up mongodb on Heroku with Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

On my local host, I have the following Node code to setup a mongoDB database name "dbname":

**users.js:**

```
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient,
    Connection = require("mongodb").Connection,
    Server = require("mongodb").Server;

Users = function(host, port) {
  var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(host, port));
  mongoClient.open(function (){});
  this.db = mongoClient.db("dbname");
};

Users.prototype.getCollection = function (callback) {
  this.db.collection("users", function (error, users) {
    if (error) callback(error);
    else callback(null, users);
  });
};

Users.prototype.findAll = function (callback) {
  this.getCollection(function (error, users) {
    if (error) {
      callback(error);
    } else {
      users.find().toArray(function (error, results) {
        if (error) {
          callback(error);
        } else {
          callback(null,results);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

// Bunch of other prototype functions...

exports.Users = Users;
```

I like to put the above database functionality in one file, and then in my main server file require that file as follows:

**server.js:**

```
var Users = require("./users").Users;
var users = new Users("localhost", 27017);
users.findAll(function (err, user) {
  // Do something
});
```

To have this working on localhost is pretty easy. In the command line, I just type the following:

```
$ mongod # to launch the database server
$ node server.js # to launch the web server
```

and it works fine. However, now I'm trying to push the whole thing onto Heroku with the mongolab addon

```
heroku addons:add mongolab
```

but the database is not running and I have no idea how to make it run. [This tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#using-mongodb) explains how to setup mongodb with the mongolab URI, but that's not how my code works, I use a host and a port and I create a new server based on that. How should I change my code for it to work on the heroku app? I want to keep the database code in a separate file, with the prototype functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Helped by Xinzz's answer, here's the modified code, so that the mongodb database is initialized with a URI instead of host + port. That's how Heroku initializes the mongodb database, and that's why it wasn't working.

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb");

var MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGOLAB_URI || process.env.MONGOHQ_URL || "mongodb://localhost", // Make sure to replace that URI with the one provided by MongoLab
    db,
    users;

mongodb.MongoClient.connect(MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db = database;
  users = db.collection("users");
  accounts = db.collection("accounts");
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
  console.log("Express server started on port %s", server.address().port);
});
```

The key here is to declare the variables db and users upfront, assign them a value in the asynchronous callback of the connect function of MongoClient and also start the app (`app.listen(...)`) in the same callback. Then later in the code I can do the following:

```
users.find().toArray(function (err, results) {
  // Do something
});
```

I also gave up on all these prototype functions, since they did not really add much.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the example [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html) at the "MongoClient.connect" section.

Essentially, you will need to change this part of the code:

```
Users = function(host, port) {
  var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(host, port));
  mongoClient.open(function (){});
  this.db = mongoClient.db("dbname");
};
```

To use mongoClient.connect() instead of new MongoClient:

```
Users = function(url) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    // Find better way to set this since this callback is asynchronous.
    this.db = db;
  });
};
```

If you are using node, I recommend using a library such as mongoose `npm install mongoose` to handle mongodb interactions. Look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379665/define-mongoose-and-schema-only-ones/20380405#20380405) for how to structure your schemas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But doesn't the fact that MongoClient.connect() is asynchronous make it impossible to structure my code the way it is? How would you write the prototype functions in this case?

Comment: That is a design decision you should try to adopt; Nodejs is only powerful BECAUSE it is asynchronous. If you try to do synchronous operations on its single-thread you will drive its performance to lower than all its alternatives. What I would do in your situation is to wrap all code inside the callback or install mongoose and follow how I structure my schemas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379665/define-mongoose-and-schema-only-ones/20380405#20380405)